# How to apply probability with a deck of cards

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For this question, I'm not sure if I am doing it right. Here is what I have so far? Can anyone please help me out?

Suppose we roll a fair six-sided die and then pick a number of cards from a
well-shuffled deck equal to the number showing on the die. (For example, if the die
shows $4$, then we pick $4$ cards.)
What is the probability that the number of jacks in our hand equals $2$?

$P(\text{rolling a number on die}) = \frac{1}{6}$

$P(\text{number of jacks $= 2$}) = \frac{1}{6}\times{^{52}C_4}\times{^{48}C_2}$

Comment: Your result is much larger than 1, so it can’t be a correct probability. Can you find the probability of drawing 2 jacks for any of the six die possibilities separately? That’s a good place to start.

Comment: 2 jacks = 2 on a die, so how are we supposed to do it separately?

Comment: Exactly 2 jacks, not more?

Comment: Yes, exactly two jacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Solution*. Let $\mathcal{J}$ denote the event that exactly two jacks are selected in addition let $D_i$ denote the event that the die roll yielded $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. We may compute $\mathbf{P(\mathcal{J})}$ by making use of bayes's formula if you observe that 
$$\mathbf{P}(\mathcal{J}) = \sum_{k=2}^{6}\mathbf{P}(\mathcal{J}|D_k)\mathbf{P}(D_k) = \frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{0}}{\binom{52}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{1}}{\binom{52}{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\dots+\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{6}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: Does 2 to 6 mean the scenarios for if it rolls a 2,3,4,5,6?

Comment: Yes indeed. It is not possible to get  $2$ jacks in the event that the die rolls a one.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the die shows $n$ (where $n \geq 2$). Then, the probability that among $n$ randomly pocked cards, the number of Jacks is equal to $2$ is

$$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{n-2}}{\binom{52}{n}}.$$

Namely, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ events that we choose $2$ out of $4$ Jacks and $\binom{48}{n-2}$ events that we choose other $n-2$ cards.  Thus we have the numerator of the expression.  It is easy to see that there are $\binom{52}{n}$ possibilities of choosing $n$ cards randomly, and this is the denominator.

Next, we are interested in all $n$ numbers that is at least $2$, or $n = \{2,3,4,5,6\}$.  The probability that each of those number show is $\frac{1}{6}$.  Then, we sum up over all $n$ to obtain the final answer:

$$\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=2}^6 \frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{n-2}}{\binom{52}{n}}.$$

Comment: Why the $\binom{n}{2}$ in the numerator?

Comment: You should have said that $n$ is greater than *or equal to* $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Assume the die roll is $m$.  There are ${m \choose 2}$ positions that the two jacks can occupy.  And three are $4*3$ possible jacks they can be.  (I'm distinguishing order; I suspect the math will be easier-- I may be wrong, but so long as I am consistent it doesn't matter).  There $\frac {48!}{(48-(m-2)!}=\frac {48!}{(50-m)!}$ ways the rest of the cards could be.  So given that the die roll is $m$ then the probability of exactly $2$ jacks is $\frac {12{m\choose 2}\frac {48!}{(50-m)!}}{\frac {52!}{52-m}!}=12{m\choose 2}\frac {48!}{52!}\frac {(52-m)!}{(50-m)!}$

And the probability that the die is $m$ is $\frac 16$.

So the probability of exactly 2 jacks is $\sum\limits_{m=1}^6 \frac 1612{m\choose 2}\frac {48!}{52!}\frac {(52-m)!}{(50-m)!}=2\frac {48!}{52!}\sum\limits_{m=1}^6{m\choose 2}\frac {(52-m)!}{(50-m)!}$

$\sum\limits_{m=1}^6{m\choose 2}\frac {(52-m)!}{(50-m)!}=$

$0*\frac {52!}{50!}+ 1*\frac {51!}{49!} + 3*\frac {50!}{48!}+ 6*\frac {49!}{47!}+ \frac{ 5*4*3}{6}\frac {48!}{46!}+ \frac {6*5*4*3}{24}\frac {47!}{45!}=$

$\frac {51!}{49!}+ 3*\frac {50!}{48!}+ 6*\frac {49!}{47!}+10\frac {48!}{46!}+15\frac {47!}{45!}=$

$51*50 + 3*50*49 + 6*49*48+10*48*47 + 15*47*46=79002=2*3^3*7*11*19$

And so $2\frac {48!}{52!}\sum\limits_{m=1}^6{m\choose 2}\frac {(52-m)!}{(48-m)!}=$

$2\frac 1{52*51*50*49}2*3^3*7*11*19=$

$\frac {3^2*7*11*19}{13*17*50*49}=\frac {13167}{541450}$

I don't know if there is a way to simplify the sum.